# Installing OpenCV on Windows 7 for Python 3.2.3

Tags: windows, opencv, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing OpenCV on Windows 7 for Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709301/installing-opencv-on-windows-7-for-python-2-7)

I'm trying to get OpenCV working with Python 3.2.3. I am aware of a [ctypes-opencv](http://code.google.com/p/ctypes-opencv/) method for Python 3.1. Ideally I'd like an installer but can't find one anywhere. I have tried to work my way through a couple of tutorials but they all seem way to complicated. If anyone could point me to a tutorial for using opencv through ctypes or anything else helpful it would be much appreciated.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286836/totally-lost-on-installing-opencv-ctypes-opencv-for-python-3

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899845/pointer-on-ctypes-to-use-opencv-on-python-3-1

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315021/installing-opencv-for-python3

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of [Installing OpenCV on Windows 7 for Python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709301/installing-opencv-on-windows-7-for-python-2-7).  The question is about Python 3.x, which has a completely different answer.  It IS a duplicate of this question, though: [OpenCV for python 3.X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709407/opencv-for-python-3-x)