# OpenCV for python 3.X

Tags: opencv, python-3.x

Does anyone know if I can use the OpenCV library in python 3.X? or should I stick to using `scikit-image` for task like object recognition?

I want to try out openCV but decided last year to swich from 2.7.

I searched for packets here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv

But none exist for python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ccsv: As of 4 June 2015, Christoph Gohlke's site is now updated with the latest release of OpenCV 3.0 with Python 3.x bindings:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can build the latest Trunk of OpenCV yourself with Python 3.x bindings.
As you can see [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/modules/python/src2) in the logs, Python 3.x support was added 2013 already and should work.
For information about how you can build OpenCV look [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#installation-by-making-your-own-libraries-from-the-source-files).