# How to install openCV 3.x for use with python 3.x in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, opencv, build, cmake

Can someone please provide a 'for dummies' list of instructions to install openCV 3.x for use with Python 3.x on Windows 10?

A Hello-World of sorts? The OpenCV site doesn't appear to have one.

I am happy to use whatever IDE but as I have used Sublime Text 2 I would prefer to keep doing so.

I have spent quite a bit of time developing a reasonably complex and succesful C++ 2.x openCV application in Visual Studio and managed (with some effort) to get that development environment working for me, but when it comes to cmake/builds/github/source/compilers and all the configurations required for Python I am facing too many free variables and unknowns (*and* my own ignorance regarding these things).

In all the tutorials, SE Q&A and other internet dialog I've discovered there is jargon heavy and includes missed steps and assumed knowledge.

Potentially irrelevant info (??) follows:

[OpenCV for Python 3.x under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489867/opencv-for-python-3-x-under-windows) looks good, but cmake is complaining:

"CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set."

Which is probably something to do with my selection of 'Sublime Text 2 - minGW' in 'configure'. Maybe not, no idea, the answer given doesn't suggest which option I'm meant to chose and why...

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is off-topic. Please modify your question. When you are usung Visual Studio, don't set the generator (-G) to MinGW

Comment: @usr1234567 ok, can someone please *provide* a 'for dummies' list of instructions? I am not using Visual Studio, I haven't got to that part yet... (This is a new install on a fresh machine.) Also, I don't know what 'generator' means - remember, I'm a dummy  :)

Comment: StackOverflow is about precise question concerning programming. Not about helping dummies. Learn some CMake and Python, dig into OpenCV. If you have any concrete problems, come back.

Comment: @usr1234567 Thanks for the hot tips, you're a real SE champion +1