# Why do i need Visual Studio for implementing OpenCV in my Windows 7.

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, python-3.4

Can i use any other IDLE instead of Visual Studio . And which version of OpenCV is compatible with python3.4

Comment: what do you mean by "implementing in windows"? do you want to start an opencv application? If you need the Runtimr Libraries you could comlile opencv with statically linked dependencies.

Comment: yes thanks i done by using inbuilt python libraries

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of IDEs for python [HERE](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments). You can also find binaries of OpenCV for different python packages [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30686903/9380191)

Comment: thanks i understood with python inbuilt libraries there is no need for explicitly having visual studio